# Jenkins on EKS can't connect to external EC2 server as Jenkins worker-node: ERROR `port:50000 is not reachable`

Tags: jenkins, amazon-ec2, amazon-eks, jenkins-agent, jenkins-x

My main task is to create a Jenkins Node from an EC2 instance/server.

Jenkins server it's on EKS deployed via `jx`

```
$ jx version

jx                 2.0.818
jenkins x platform 2.0.1376
Kubernetes cluster v1.13.12
kubectl            v1.17.0
helm client        Client: v2.16.1
git                2.23.0
Operating System   Mac OS X 10.15.4
```

The problems I am facing:

- The Helm chart for Jenkins deploys 2 services named `jenkins-agent` and `jenkins`. [related issue](https://www.gitmemory.com/issue/helm/charts/7360/498268052)
- The ingress it's configured by default to use just `jenkins` service as backend and port `50000` isn't reachable for external agents via HOST.
- I can't edit the `jenkins` ingress to point at service `jenkins` with 2 backend ports `8080` & `50000` (ingress allows just one port per service/path!). [related issue](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/issues/1655#issuecomment-342222762)

You can see here that here is 2 services: 1 `jenkins` for Jenkins controller and one for Jenkins agent `jenkins-agent`, but only one ingress `jenkins` which points to `jenkins` svc backend on port `8080`.

```
$ kubectl get svc
NAME                        TYPE           CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP    PORT(S)
heapster                    ClusterIP       ************    <none>         8082/TCP
jenkins                     ClusterIP       ************    <none>         8080/TCP
jenkins-agent               ClusterIP      ************     <none>         50000/TCP
jenkins-x-chartmuseum       ClusterIP      ************     <none>         8080/TCP
jenkins-x-docker-registry   ClusterIP     ************      <none>         5000/TCP



$ kubectl get ingress
NAME              HOSTS                             ADDRESS            PORTS
chartmuseum       chartmuseum.**                    ***.amazonaws.com   80  
docker-registry   docker-registry.**                ***.amazonaws.com   80
jenkins           jenkins.**                        ***.amazonaws.com   80
```

I tried to create another ingress specific for `jenkins-agent` svc and to use something like     `alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/group.name: mygroup`. [info link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58380144)

I failed to bind 2 ingresses together, unfortunately the `jenkins` ingress has `kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx` and  `ingress.class` does't have this feature...

I checked the SecurityGroups to have the port `50000` open.

I tried to go on AWS and to add manually a `50000` port to load balancer but still when I am running on EC2 this command:

```
java -jar agent.jar -jnlpUrl http://JENKINS_URL/computer/****-service/slave-agent.jnlp -secret ****** -workDir "/home/ec2-user/jenkins_home" -failIfWorkDirIsMissing
```

Fails with this Error:

```
provided port:50000 is not reachable
```

How to add an external Jenkins agent to a Jenkins which 2 services one for UI and Another for Agent. The above `java` command requires both ports to be open!

On the same `PATH` because you need port 8080 to get the `slave-agent.jnlp` and after you get it, in the background it's trying to connect to port `50000`

I am out of ideas...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After experimenting all day...

I came with a solution, it's not the best or straight forward but at least it's working. My slave is connected! `INFO: Connected`

So, I edited the `jenkins-agent` service and from `type: ClusterIP` I changed to  `type: LoadBalancer`. That gave me a new fresh loadbalancer and after I decided to add the port `8080` because in the service yaml file it's using the same `selector` as in `jenkins` service.

(**jenkins-agent** service yaml)

```
  spec:
  clusterIP: ***
  externalTrafficPolicy: Cluster
  ports:
  - name: slavelistener
    nodePort: 30258
    port: 50000
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 50000
  - name: http
    nodePort: 30840
    port: 8080
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 8080
  selector:
    component: jenkins-x-jenkins-master
  sessionAffinity: None
  type: LoadBalancer
status:
  loadBalancer:
    ingress:
    - hostname: ****
```

After I had just to add the port `8080` at the end of my new `jenkins-agent` load balancer:

```
java -jar agent.jar -jnlpUrl http://****.elb.amazonaws.com:8080/computer/***-service/slave-agent.jnlp -secret ***** -workDir "/home/ec2-user/jenkins_home" -failIfWorkDirIsMissing
```

[image: INFO: Connected]